# 3 ряда друг под другом flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Всем привет,сейчас будет ОЧЕНЬ ТУПОЙ вопрос. за случился затык.
как расположить 3 ряда друг под другом во флексах?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.who-list{
 margin-top:40px;
 display: inline-block;
 border:1px solid;
}

.who-list-wrap{
 border:1px solid;
 
}
.who-list_item{
 
 vertical-align: top;
 margin-top:50px;
}

.who-list_item-title{
 font-family: HelveticaNeueCyr;
 line-height: 30px;
 font-size: 26px;
 color: #333333;
 font-weight: 700;
 margin-bottom: 18px;
}

.who-list_item-desc{
 font-family: HelveticaNeueCyr;
 line-height: 26px;
 font-size: 20px;
 letter-spacing: 0.4px;
 color: #333333;

}
```

```html
 <div class="who-list">
   
  <div class="who-list-wrap">
   <div class="who-list_item">
    <div class="who-list_item-icon"><img src="img/who/1.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="who-list_item-content">
     <h4 class="who-list_item-title">Для руководителей предприятий</h4>
     <p class="who-list_item-desc">
      Комплексный анализ контрагента, его ответственности и поведения на рынке позволит Вам заключать договоры только с надёжными компаниями и защитит от осечек при выборе партнёров
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>

  
   <div class="who-list_item">
    <div class="who-list_item-icon"><img src="img/who/2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="who-list_item-content">
     <h4 class="who-list_item-title">Для отделов продаж</h4>
     <p class="who-list_item-desc">
      Помогает найти потенциальных клиентов и проверить сферы их деятельности     .
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="who-list-wrap">
   <div class="who-list_item">
    <div class="who-list_item-icon"><img src="img/who/3.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="who-list_item-content">
     <h4 class="who-list_item-title">Для службы безопасности       </h4>
     <p class="who-list_item-desc">
      Поможет выявить фирмы-однодневки, покажет аффилированность      .
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>
 


 
   <div class="who-list_item">
    <div class="who-list_item-icon"><img src="img/who/4.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="who-list_item-content">
     <h4 class="who-list_item-title">Для юристов</h4>
     <p class="who-list_item-desc">
      Покажет арбитражную практику, сложившуюся в отношении фирмы-контрагента     .
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="who-list-wrap">
   <div class="who-list_item">
    <div class="who-list_item-icon"><img src="img/who/5.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="who-list_item-content">
     <h4 class="who-list_item-title">Для главных бухгалтеров</h4>
     <p class="who-list_item-desc">
      Модуль поможет уменьшить налоговые риски     .
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="who-list_item">
    <div class="who-list_item-icon"><img src="img/who/6.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="who-list_item-content">
     <h4 class="who-list_item-title">Для тендерных отделов     </h4>
     <p class="who-list_item-desc">
      Покажет информацию о торгах контрагента и их результатах     .
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  </div>
```

---

все, ответ снят,решил сделать ширину 50 процентов

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы просто не прочитать про `flexbox`? В любом случае это можно сделать с помощью указания направления `flexbox` используя параметр `flex-direction`.

```css
.wrapper
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper > .flex-wrapper
{
  flex: 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 10px;
}


.wrapper > .flex-wrapper > .flex-block
{
  flex: 1 auto;
  margin: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flex-wrapper">
    <div class="flex-block">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-block">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-block">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-wrapper">
    <div class="flex-block">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-block">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-block">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```